# How to fix - org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException exception

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I have jhipster application , with mongodb.I was able to sucessfully build prod version. when i run the prod build war file in windows ( which is same as my dev machine) it works fine. when I deploy the war to linux and try to access particular link got the below exception

```
    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expected static field jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.undefined

com.mastercard.rsc.web.rest.ResultssummaryResource.getAllResultssummariesByBuild(ResultssummaryResource.java:121)
```

Below is code where the above exception is pointing to . what i am trying to do is if the buildversion is not empty the fetch the records filter by build version if buildversion is not provided then fetch all the records. In my request the build version is not empty i am passing the value CurlVersion and the matching records is in the DB.

```
public ResponseEntity<List<ResultssummaryDTO>> getAllResultssummariesByBuild(Pageable pageable,@RequestParam(value = "buildversion", required = false) String buildversion) {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Resultssummaries by Build Version");
    System.out.println(buildversion);
    if (buildversion != undefined) {
        Page<ResultssummaryDTO> page = resultssummaryService.findByBuildversion(pageable, buildversion);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/resultssummaries");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    else {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Resultssummaries");
        Page<ResultssummaryDTO> page = resultssummaryService.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/resultssummaries");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(page.getContent(), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I think the problem could be in the way i check the build version,

```
if (buildversion != undefined)
```

but how come it works in windows(the same prod build war). also when i debug it works fine .not sure why the issue happens when i run in linux. 
don't know sure what options to try totally blank.
can you help to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `undefined` value from javascript (using Nashorn) in your java backend, try comparing `buildversion` with `null` and get rid of nashorn import.

Comment: Thanks will try the option and accept your solution as answer